# Where will the memory be allocated in the following piece of code?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-allocation, static-allocation

If I declare a `std::vector<A *>`, where will the memory be allocated? I know `new` dynamically allocates memory, but the memory for the vector should be allocated statically. I want to know what happens with the memory.

```
    typedef std::vector<A *> AArray;

    void myFunction()
    {
        AArray aarray;
        aarray.push_back(new A());
        aarray.push_back(new A());
    }
```

Comment: STL data structures never use "static" memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AArray aarray;` will allocate memory on the stack for your vector.

`aarray.push_back(new A());` Will construct an `A` on the heap and then return a pointer to it that will be placed in your container.

Comment: The first sentence is rather misleading. It will allocate a small amount of stack for a few variables to manage the array of pointers; the array itself will be dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::vector` needs to be able to change it's allocated data, which means it will keep an allocated array (an (A*)[] in this case) internally. This array will be allocated on the heap (dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

This will cause memory leaks every time `myFunction()` is called. The variable `aarray` is local to `myFunction()` and is allocated statically, hence it is destroyed as soon as the control returns from the function. However, the two objects of class `A` are created dynamically, and are not destroyed automatically by C++. You have to use `delete` to delete these objects. You have not deleted the objects in your code, so these two objects will remain unreferenced in memory, causing a memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. I had a similar piece of code in my project and had some trouble with the deallocation of the memory on stack. I solved the problem, but I still wanted to know how the memory is managed in such a case. The actual code was a lot different and the memory allocated in `myFunction` was later used and referenced.